# How to use Chrome element inspector to inspect marker icons in Google Maps API application?

Tags: google-maps-api, chrome

I have some json data that are loaded with **google maps API** `map.Data layer`, I want to inspect the marker icon element (as shown as stars in the attached picture), what's the trick to use browser element inspector to do that?

Currently no matter how I try, the inspector just doesn't select the hovered stars (json markers from the `Data layer`).

[image]

**Update**

Data Layer marker icon can be inspected directly from dom tree. 
The selector for these icons is `'img[src*="data:"]'`. Through this way, additional css styles can be applied to the icons to improve the UX.

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps API uses canvas to draw the markers, you wouldn't be able to inspect them as they are not elements.

EDIT:
[Google Maps Javascript API Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases)- contains the changes to support canvas.
[Possible workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278051/google-maps-v3-disable-canvas-markers)- there is a [property](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#MarkerOptions) that let you render it as a DOM element. However, I would only use that for debugging purposes and not on a live website.

Comment: After digging into the DOM tree, I managed to inspect the json layer icons with the inspector as element. they have tags start with <img data: ...>